# Trying to bind DBcontext to Telerik Autocomplete Box.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, telerik

I am trying to bind a list that I pull of "string" that comes from my db context to this autocomplete telerik control box:

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
        <br />
    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ID="GridSortSearch" runat="server" InputType="Token" CssClass="center-block"></telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
        <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitSortSearch" runat="server" Text="Sort Grid" OnClick="btnSubmitSortSearch_Click" />       
    </div> 

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        PopulateDDL();
        GridSortSearch.DataSource = dbContext.DownloadTypes.ToList(); 
    }
```

This is what is displayed: [image]

and I have no clue why, please help! Thank you!

Comment: Have you set the values for text and value for the GridSortSearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the **DataTextField** and **DataValueField** of the RadAutoCompleteBox control and call the **DataBind()** method after setting up the DataSource property.

Here is the help topic:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox-databinding-datasource.html